# Zend_Db order by field Value

Tags: sql, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

I'm outputting the contents of a select menu from a model using this:

```
$select = $this->select();
$select->order('name');
return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

However, what i want to do is order by a specific value, and then by the name column. The SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `names` ORDER BY `name` = 'SomeValue' DESC,`name`
```

**SAMPLE SQL CODE:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'rob'),
(2, 'dave'),
(3, 'andy'),
(4, 'paul'),
(5, 'jason'),
(6, 'john');

SELECT *
FROM `names`
ORDER BY `name` = 'john' DESC , `name`
```

RETURNS:

```
6   john
3   andy
2   dave
5   jason
4   paul
1   rob
```

Comment: and in what order does that (very weird) query return the entries?

Comment: $select->order("name = 'john' DESC , name"); does not work ?

Comment: @tharkun: john, andy, dave, jason, paul, rob find it kinda strange to..

Comment: if this returns john first and then everybody else, then you really can't call this order by entry. it's much rather a take john out of the order, place him in the beginning and then order the rest by name.

Comment: didn't know something like that exists. interesting.

Comment: nope, Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name = 'john'' in 'order clause'

Comment: can't find this in the mysql documentation either. Maybe you should work with IF THEN or CASE. I guess either way you'll have to write your query out, I don't think the Zend_Db wrapper supports this.

Comment: try to set $select->setIntegrityCheck(false)

Comment: $select->setIntegrityCheck(false) doesnt work, docs say thats only relevant to table joins anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
$name = 'John';
$order = new Zend_Db_Expr($this->getAdapter()->quoteInto("name = ?", $name) ." DESC, `name`");
$select = $this->select();
$select->order($order);
return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on your SQL DB, this is not supported. (i dont know a database which can sort directly by a string.)

what would you want to accomplish ? have fields with someValue at the first positions

Comment: This is possible with MySQL as i use that query in an older system

Comment: possible by not throughing an error, but dont sort like i would expect.

can you give us an example table with data and what sorting you want to achive ?