# order by fields listing the name

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a database like this

```
CREATE TABLE `xyz` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO `xyz` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'train'),
(2, 'bus'),
(3, 'bus'),
(4, 'bus'),
(5, 'train'),
(6, 'train'),
(7, 'train'),
(8, 'car'),
(9, 'car'),
(10, 'car');
```

I want to sort by name example train is selecting train, all train are fields.
how to write this program in zend-framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162709/zend-db-order-by-field-value

Comment: Thanks gowri for your helping, but not this exactly i want. i have a site , selected train field shows all the train records in that site

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `xyz` ORDER BY `name`
```